# What can i do in Oracle in order to preserve the savepoint if internal commit occurs?

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, plsql, refactoring

**background:**
i'm doing some Oracle plsql refactoring; The first think that i want to accomplish is to have unit test for the principal components.

For this i'm using ruby with the gem plsq-spec https://github.com/rsim/ruby-plsql-spec

In order to execute the tests several times, i'm using Oracle Savepoints after open the database conection, and doing a rollback to the savepoint before close the connection

**Problem:**
Some test can't be executed more than one time, because some procedures had internal commits.

*What can i do in Oracle in order to preserve the savepoint if internal commit/rollback occurs?*

With this information in the note apparently what I want is impossible
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/savepoint_statement.htm

> A simple rollback or commit erases all savepoints. When you roll back
>   to a savepoint, any savepoints marked after that savepoint are erased.
>   The savepoint to which you roll back remains.

so, the only solutions are?:

- modify the procedures
- erase all data before execute the tests?

tks

Comment: In my opinion, PL/SQL procedures should never commit. So I'd go for modifying the procedures and moving all COMMITs to the client code.

Comment: I agree, but this solution may take some time, because there are no documentation, no unit test, and 20 years of a complete lack of governance and standards, and 3 million lines of code.

Comment: In that case, I'd add some kind of global configuration (context, package variable, ...) and change the PL/SQL procedures to check this global config whether they should commit or not (default: do commit). This way, your production code should work as before, and your unit tests can set the global configuration to "do not commit" and perform a rollback afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

The Flashback feature may help you here, as you can restore the database or individual tables to their state as-of a previous point in time.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9012.htm

Comment: tks, the only problem with flashback is that when you make the SCN mark and revert to that mark, all other changes after the mark will be lost too (other tests, developer changes, etc)

Comment: Yes, that's true. It's even worse if other session have made changes dependent on your changes (eg. added a child record based on a parent record that you have inserted). However, you ought to be able to arrange your own database to test on at no additional licensing cost.